# Recursion within a class in python

Tags: python, class, oop, data-structures

I know this is a very basic question and I found sample codes online but I cannot figure out why it works.

If we need to traverse a binary tree in preorder fashion, one of the way to do so (quoted here http://interactivepython.org/courselib/static/pythonds/Trees/TreeTraversals.html) is by using something like:

```
def preorder(self):
     print(self.key)
     if self.leftChild:
        self.leftChild.preorder()
     if self.rightChild:
        self.rightChild.preorder()
```

I don't understand why doing something like `self.leftChild.preorder()` is possible. If someone can point me in the right direction, I will really appreciate it.

EDIT:

As suggested in the comments, I am posting the full-code I am working on. I got it from firecode:

```
post_ordered_list = []
class BinaryTree:

    def __init__(self, root_data):
        self.data = root_data
        self.left_child = None
        self.right_child = None

    def postorder(self):
        if self.left_child:
            self.left_child.postorder()
        if self.right_child:
            self.right_child.postorder()
        post_ordered_list.append(self.data)
        return post_ordered_list


    def get_right_child(self):
        return self.right_child

    def get_left_child(self):
        return self.left_child

    def set_root_val(self, obj):
        self.data = obj

    def get_root_val(self):
        return self.data
```

Comment: You would probably need to include the class definition in your question for us to make sense of one of its methods

Comment: Added the whole class

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you don't understand? Why wouldn't `self.leftChild.preorder()` be possible?

Comment: Yes. Why does `self.leftChild.preorder()` work? LeftChild is an instance attribute, correct? How does it connect to preorder method?

Comment: The thing that's not shown in your code, but is almost certainly true is `self.leftChild` and `self.rightChild` are themselves instances of `BinaryTree` so they also have a `preorder()` method.

Comment: @MarkMeyer you want to say that outside of the class, there is something like `left_child=BinaryTree(data)`?

Comment: @EminMammadov yes, the code doesn't show how the child nodes are added, but in most implementations they would be trees also. It doesn't have to be outside the class, but it's not shown in the class in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, `classInstance.methodName(params...)` is equivalent to invocation of some class's `methodName` method, with `classInstance` passed as `self`:

1. Determine which class is `classInstance`, which you can get with `type(classInstance)` or `classInstance.__class__` (look for `classInstance = Class(...)` instantiation code).
2. Determine if the class defines `methodName` with `self` as the first parameter. `self` being the first parameter indicates that it is an instance method, not class method or static method (see below for link explaining). If there is such a method, then invoke it with `self` being `classInstance`, i.e. the equivalent invocation would be `Class.methodName(classInstance, params...)`.
3. If the class does not define `methodName`, then look for the closest ancestor that does, following documentation for [inheritance](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance), and do likewise. In this case, the equivalent invocation would look like: `ParentClass.methodName(classInstnace, params...)`.

Here's an example:

```
n4 = BinaryTree(4)
n5 = BinaryTree(5)
n3 = BinaryTree(3)
n3.left_child = n5
n3.right_child = n4
"""
  3
 /  \
4    5
"""

n3.postorder()
# result [5, 4, 3]
```

When calling `n3.postorder()`

- `self` is `n3`
- `self.leftchild` is `n5`
- `self.rightchild` is `n4`.

When `n3.postorder()` is executed, the next line is `self.left_child.postorder()`, and invokes the `postorder` method with `self.leftchild` (i.e. `n5`) as the first parameter (i.e. "self") of `postorder`. Therefore, in this recursive call's context:

- `self` is `n5`
- `self.leftchild` is `None`
- `self.rightchild` is `None`.

Then that method call finishes and the next line, `self.right_child.postorder()` executes, and it's the same thing as above, but with `n4`, since we are back in the original context, where `self.right_child` is `n4`.

In-depth documentation is available at: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

Difference between instance, class, and static methods:
https://julien.danjou.info/guide-python-static-class-abstract-methods/

Comment: In the very first sentence, you `classInstance.methodName(params...)`, which makes sense. However, left_child is not a class instance, correct? So, why can I do `self.left_child.postorder()`? If it would be something like this `BinaryTree.postorder(self.left_child))`, then I would understand (this is how I solved the problem but looking at solutions and posted answers, it seems like everyone is using another method)

Comment: Updated answer to include inheritance. `left_child` **is** a class instance. You can do `self.left_child.postorder()` because `self.left_child` is `n5`, and `n5` is of type `BinaryTree`, since `n5` was defined using `n5 = BinaryTree(5)`.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is something that is hard to grasp when starting out with programming. One of the things that you have to realize is that, if you properly have set up base cases (eg. if self.left, if self.right, etc), you can use the function that you are working on as if it is already working.

Let's think about an example of counting all the nodes in a tree with the function `countNodes()`:
Say we have node x that is somewhere in the tree. When x is called to count all of the nodes of its subtree, how does it do that?
Remember how I said that we have to pretend the function `countNodes()` exists and that it already works? Well, let's do just that.
X needs to count itself because it is a node. Therefore the count is 1 so far. After it counted itself, it has to count all the nodes on the left and all the nodes on the right. So to count the nodes in a tree starting at any node x, we call countNodes() for the left and countNodes() for the right.

So the code would look like this:

```
def countNodes(self):
    count = 1
    if self.left: #Checking to see if we have a left subtree
        count += countNodes(self.left)
    if self.right: #Checking to see if we have a right subtree
        count += countNodes(self.right)
    return count
```

So now that we understand recursion better, let's get back to your example. We want to traverse the tree in preorder fashion. So that means, by definition, that we have to visit our node first. Then we see if we have a left node to visit. If so we traverse the left nodes in a preorder fashion. If we have a right node, we traverse that entire tree in a preorder fashion as well.

Biggest takeaways of recursion:

1. Make sure you have good base cases (if node.right == null for example)
2. Find the pattern of repetition. You can use the function in the function as if it already is built as long as you have properly working base cases.

I hope that helps!

Edit:

To explain the self portion that I failed to answer. Self represents whatever object called the method. So if we have a node x that we wanted to do preorder traversal with we would use `x.preorder()`. Then in the function, it would look like this:

```
def preorder(self): #self is whatever calls this function
    print(self.value) #whaver you want to print
    if self.left:
       self.left.preorder() #now in this function call, self will be self.left
   if self.right:
       self.right.preorder() #same idea here


root.preorder() #calling the function. Now self will be root.
```

I hope that clears some things up for you. Sorry for not understanding the problem at first. I hope this answers it. Let me know if you have more questions or need some more clarification.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I understand the recursion part. I don't fully understand OOP part. Why can I do something like self.left_child.postorder()? I cannot wrap my head around using a instance attribute, which in my understanding is variable ( I can pass any integer I want and assign it to left_child) to access a method. In my understanding, those `.` mean that I access a method within a class. So, if that would be something like `tree= BinaryTree()` and then `tree.post_order()`, no problem.

Comment: Oh okay. I see where the confusion is now. Basically, python is at first kind of confusing as to what self is. If we have a node called x that we want to traverse in preorder fashion, we say x.preorder(). The x is the object, and we're saying that we want to call preorder on the node x.
Self is basically the object that called the method. In this case, it would be x. So the self.left is referring to x.left, self.right is referring to x.right. Because x called the function, x becomes self.
I hope that clears up some confusion.

Comment: So, `self.left_child` actually creates an object?

Comment: No, it doesn't. It is calling the member variable that each node object shares. Each node has a left and a right node that is attached to it. Maybe this could help. 

https://micropyramid.com/blog/understand-self-and-__init__-method-in-python-class/

Answer (score 0):

Recursion has two steps: the base case and the recursive case.  The base case stops the recursion, but from what I understand from your post, you're looking for why the recursive case works.  The key to a recursive case is that the next recurse is smaller than the one that called it.

Your preorder function takes the root as its parameter. The first time you call preorder, you are using self as the parameter, meaning that you're taking in the whole tree.  If the root has a left child, then the next step is to consider the left subtree.  The left subtree's root is the current root's left child, so that gets passed in as a parameter. You continue to recurse down the left side as long as there is a left child.  The recursion stops when there is no left child and the code continues to the right-child if statement for that last node.

I could continue, but not without being confusing.  (Hopefully I'm not already confusing!)  Check out [this page](http://www.algolist.net/Data_structures/Binary_search_tree/Lookup) on a binary search which is a very similar action.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I understand the recursion part. My confusion lays in the area of OOP. In my understanding, self.left_child is the instance attribute. If that would be an object let's say `tree=BinaryTree()`, then I would understand that I can do something like `tree.postorder()`; I am using my instance to access one of the methods, in this case postorder(). However, I am using an instance attribute (in my understanding, it is a variable that will get a value that will be passed to it) and I don't understand how I can use instance attribute to access a method within that class.

Comment: left_child and right_child are also typed to be BinaryTree.  It's a little harder to see types in Python than in some other languages like Java or C++. A variable's type is determined by how you use it, so it's exactly that you call postorder() on left_child and right_child that determines that those variables are a BinaryTree.